# Large numbers multiplication in R

Tags: r

I want to know how can I calculate large values multiplication in R.
R returns Inf!

For example:

```
6.350218e+277*2.218789e+215 
[1] Inf
```

Let me clarify the problem more:
consider the following code and the results of outFunc function:

```
library(hypergeo)
poch <-function(a,b) gamma(a+b)/gamma(a)
n<-c(37 , 41 , 4 , 9 , 12 , 13 , 2 , 5 , 23 , 73 , 129 , 22 , 121 )
v<-c(90.2, 199.3, 61, 38, 176.3, 293.6, 318.6, 328.7, 328.1, 313.3, 142.4, 92.9, 95.5)
DF<-data.frame(n,v)


outFunc<-function(k,w,r,lam,a,b) {
  ((((w*lam)^k) * poch(r,k) * poch(a,b) ) * hypergeo(r+k,a+k,a+b+k,-(w*lam)) )/(poch(a+k,b)*factorial(k))

}
```

and the function returns:

```
outFunc(DF$n,DF$v,0.2, 1, 3, 1)
 [1] 0.002911330+  0i 0.003047594+  0i 0.029886646+  0i 0.013560599+  0i 0.010160073+  0i
 [6] 0.008928524+  0i 0.040165795+  0i 0.019402318+  0i 0.005336008+  0i 0.001689114+  0i
[11]         Inf+NaNi 0.005577985+  0i         Inf+NaNi
```

As can be seen above, outFunc returns Inf+NaNi for n values of 129 and 121.
I checked the code sections part by part and I find that the returned results of (w*lam)^k* poch(r,k) for these n values are Inf. I also check my code with equivalent code in Mathematica which everything is OK:

```
in:  out[indata[[All, 1]], indata[[All, 2]], 0.2, 1, 3, 1]

out: {0.00291133, 0.00304759, 0.0298866, 0.0135606, 0.0101601, 0.00892852, \
      0.0401658, 0.0194023, 0.00533601, 0.00168911, 0.000506457, \
      0.00557798, 0.000365445}
```

Now please let me know how we can solve this issue as simple as it is in Mathematica. regards.

Comment: try `gmp::mul.bigz(6.350218e+277, 2.218789e+215)`

Comment: Or use [Brobdingnag](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Brobdingnag/index.html) library

Comment: thanks  Khashaa 2  but it returns: Error in mul.bigz(6.350218e+277 * 2.218789e+215) : 
  argument "e2" is missing, with no default

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you need this? Usually, you would work on the log-scale and report the result as `exp(1135.517)` or `10^493.1489`.

Comment: @MahdiHadi Regarding your last comment, you should work on your reading comprehension. There is no `*` in Khashaa's code.

Comment: (+1) - Clear question. No obvious related question. Reproducible. Short. Just a friendly reminder to SO users that we should reward good practices regardless of the overall interest in the question.

Comment: @Marcinthebox I do not agree. The question doesn't demonstrate any research effort.

Comment: @Roland - fair enough.

Comment: gmp::mul.bigz(6.350218e+277, 2.218789e+215) can not resolved the problem because when I use this in my equations it returns: Error in `*.bigz`((mul.bigz(((w * lam)^k), poch(r, k)) * poch(a, b)),  : 
  only logical, numeric or character (atomic) vectors can be coerced to 'bigz'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For first, I'd recommend two useful reads: [logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) and [how floating values are handled by a computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). These are pertinent because with some "tricks" you can handle much bigger values than you think. For instance, your definition of the `poch` function is terrible. This because the fraction can be simplified a lot but a computer will evaluate the numerator first and if it overflows the result will be useless. That's why `R` provides beside `gamma` the `lgamma` function: it just calculates the logarithm of `gamma` and can handle much bigger values. So, we calculate the `log` of each factor in your function and then we use `exp` to restore the intended values. Try this:

```
#redefine poch properly
poch<-function(a,b) lgamma(a+b) - lgamma(a)
#redefine outFunc
outFunc<-function(k,w,r,lam,a,b) {
   exp((k*(log(w)+log(lam))+ poch(r,k) + poch(a,b) ) +  
   log(hypergeo(r+k,a+k,a+b+k,-(w*lam)))- poch(a+k,b)-lgamma(k+1))
}
#Now we go
outFunc(DF$n,DF$v,0.2, 1, 3, 1)
#[1] 0.0029113299+0i 0.0030475939+0i 0.0298866458+0i 0.0135605995+0i
#[5] 0.0101600732+0i 0.0089285243+0i 0.0401657947+0i 0.0194023182+0i
#[9] 0.0053360084+0i 0.0016891144+0i 0.0005064566+0i 0.0055779850+0i
#[13] 0.0003654449+0i
```

Comment: There is also `lfactorial`.

Comment: @Roland Yes, of course, since `factorial` is just a wrapper of `gamma` (and `lfactorial` of `lgamma`).

Comment: Very thanks nicola, now there is need I think more with new equations.

Comment: Dear nicola check your recommended code with n<-c(22,  23 , 60,  43,  63 ,  9, 259, 167 , 61, 103) and v<-c(168.92,  27.08, 168.28, 189.60, 487.37, 490.35, 272.79, 487.98, 490.48, 489.74) then see the results of outFunc(DF$n,DF$v,0.2, 1, 3, 1), now there is problem with large values in exp() which return Inf again, what is your solution? thanks

Answer (score 6):

One option you have available in base R, which does not require a special library, is to convert the two numbers to a common base, and then add the exponents together to get the final result:

```
> x <- log(6.350218e+277, 10)
> x
[1] 277.8028
> y <- log(2.218789e+215, 10)
> y
[1] 215.3461
> x + y
[1] 493.1489
```

Since `10^x * 10^y = 10^(x+y)`, your final answer is `10^493.1489`

Note that this solution does not allow to actually store numbers which R would normally treat as `INF`.  Hence, in this example, you still cannot compute `10^493`, but you can tease out what the product would be.

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that floating point precision plays a role, but is usually not relevant for numbers of this magnitude.

Comment: As I recall from my childhood, infinity plus one is still infinity :-)

Comment: Dear Tim Biegeleisen but result of 10^493.1489 in R is yet Inf  and problem is not resolved!!!!!!

Comment: @MahdiHadi If you need to work with data too large, then I believe you will have to resort to a custom library.  Base R cannot handle the calculation you gave in your OP, though my answer lets you at least see what the answer is.

Comment: this two values are one simple multiplication in my complex formulas thus I think R is weak for programming when we have large values in calculations. What is your mean about custom library?

Comment: If your calculation only requires precision within one exponent, then my method might go pretty far for you.  If you really need to handle such large numbers with precision, I believe you will need a custom library for this.

Comment: @MahdiHadi R is not "weak for programming". You have a weak understanding for how computers handle numbers.

Comment: Ok Ronald I am weak to understand how the computer  handles numbers, But why Mathematica (as you can see above) handles this problem very simply?

Comment: Mathematica is unusual in using arbitrary precision for numerical calculations by default (unique? Python uses arbitrary precision for *integer* calculations). It's not a good SO question but I'm curious whether there's any other mainstream computer language that does so.

Answer (score 4):

```
> library(gmp)
> x<- pow.bigz(6.350218,277)
> y<- pow.bigz(2.218789,215)
> x*y

Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 18592826814872791919942226542714580401488894909642693257011204682802122918146288728149155739011270579948954646130492024596687919148494136290260248656581476275790189359808616520170359345612068099238508437236172770752199936303947098513476300142414338199993261924467166943683593371648
```